# Why do\textit and \emph suddenly not work anymore?

Tags: fonts

I use LaTeX, TeX Studio, LuaLaTex. Yesterday, the document compiled just fine. Although I have changed not a single line of code, \textit doesn't work anymore within the document-environment - neither if used on its own or as part of self-defined commands. It does work in the title, though. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel,ulem,libertine}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[firstinits]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{Bibliographie-Trimalchio-Lucan.bib}
\title{Outside/In: Pompey outside of Lucan's \textit{Bellum Civile} and Trimalchio in the \textit{Satyricon}}
\author{Patrick Kappacher}
\date{April 14, 2017}
\newcommand{\BC}{\textit{Bellum Civile}}
\newcommand{\Luc}{Lucan}
\newcommand{\Petr}{Petronius}
\newcommand{\Sat}{\textit{Satyricon}}
\newcommand{\HO}{handout}
\newcommand{\CT}{\textit{Cena Trimalchionis}}
\newcommand{\C}{\textit{Cena}}
\newcommand{\lib}{\textit{libertas}}
\newcommand{\umb}{\textit{umbra}}
\newcommand{\umbs}{\textit{umbrae}}
\newcommand{\nom}{\textit{nomen}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
{\doublespacing

\BC~should be in Italics, but it isn't. \textit{Neither is this}.
\emph{Does not work either.}

 }         

\pagebreak
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! You have a `{` which does not have a closing. But otherwise you MWE works fine for me and I get italic text https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzuIV.png Can you add 1) a screenshot of your output from the above code? 2) the `.log` file?

Comment: mine looks like this: http://pastebin.com/3vAcHJ0j

Comment: I believe that the libertine package has been undergoing recent [updates](http://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.251.1490132274.4791.ctan-ann@ctan.org). You might check that by using some other font and seeing what happens. If that does it, then you can report a bug to the package maintainer.

Comment: OK, so you have a newer luatex version the me. Unfortunately I can currently not update to test, but hopefully someone else with an up to date luatex may test this.

Comment: Charles, you are right: Changing the font to the standard LaTeX-font solves the problem!

Comment: @RobtA you mean with your class loading libertine package with lualatex doesn't use opentype fonts?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done. But I'll retain some of my earlier advice: With LuaLaTeX and fontspec, consider using `\setmainfont` and consider `polyglossia` as an alternative to `babel`.

Comment: @RobtA the whole point of the package is that it loads fontspec and a matching set of fonts, with font features set to match the package options.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just realized that the libertine Open Type fonts are now libertinus fonts! Apparently Libertinus Serif now replaces Linux Libertine O, Libertinus Sans O replaces Linux Biolinum, etc. Fine by me. But this is more than just a routine package update. When using `fontspec` to directly find the libertine fonts by font family name, it will now fail. From my perspective, this is actually an improvement (after I adjust my own code). But how many users realize that the fonts themselves have been changed?

Comment: well forked rather than became. I don't know the politics behind it but libertinus has always been describes as a fork of the original linux libertine project see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertinus?lang=en for example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Update: It turns out that the libertine maintainer had inadvertently uploaded Libertinus to CTAN. Was supposed to be an experiment, not live. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The file  LinLibertine_RI.otf was corrupted in a recent libertine update.  A corrected package has been uploaded to CTAN.